# Form handling PHP PDO

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I'm playing around with a form trying to learn PDO.
The problem is that nothing is submitted. Nothing is saved and I don´t receive any errors.

I have a class (ABB). In that class I have a function called "spara_abb" (along with several functions used in the script).

Questions:

- Is there any way to complete this code to work?
- Is this the right way to solve this?

Any suggestions?

**The form:**

```
<?php  

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $save_abb = $abb->spara_abb($_POST['ident']);                   
}

?>

<!-- FORM START - Create new ABB -->
<form action="abb_ny.php?amne_id=<?php echo $_GET['amne_id']; ?>&abb_arskurs=<?php echo $_GET['abb_arskurs']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sky-form1" class="sky-form">
    <input type='Hidden' name='lid' value='<? echo $_SESSION['lid']; ?>'>
    <input type='Hidden' name='datum' value='<? echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>'>
    <input type='Hidden' name='ident' value='<? echo $abb->skapa_ident($_GET['amne_id']); ?>'>
    <input type='Hidden' name='amne_id' value='<? echo $_GET['amne_id']; ?>'>
    <input type='Hidden' name='arskurs' value='<? echo $_GET['abb_arskurs']; ?>'>
    <input type='Hidden' name='aktiv' value='1'>

    <header>Skapa ny ABB</header>                      
    <fieldset>

    <section>
        <label class="label">Arbetsomrade</label>
        <label class="input">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
        <input type="text" name="arbetsomrade" id="arbetsomrade" placeholder="Arbetsområde">
        </label>
    </section>

    <label class="label">Syfte</label>
    <section>                            
        <label class="textarea">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
        <textarea rows="5" name="syfte" placeholder="Syfte"></textarea>
        </label>
    </section>

    <label class="label">Overgripande mal</label>
    <section>                            
        <label class="textarea">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
        <textarea rows="5" name="overgripande_mal" placeholder="Övergripande mål"></textarea>
        </label>
    </section>  

    <label class="label">Undervisning</label>
    <section>                            
        <label class="textarea">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
        <textarea rows="5" name="undervisning" placeholder="Undervisning"></textarea>
        </label>
    </section>  

    <label class="label">Redovisningsform</label>
    <section>                            
        <label class="textarea">
        <i class="icon-append fa fa-comment"></i>
        <textarea rows="5" name="redovisningsform" placeholder="Redovisningsform"></textarea>
        </label>
    </section>

    </fieldset>

    <footer>
        <button type="submit" name="Spara" value="Spara" class="btn-u">Save ABB</button>     
    </footer> 

</form>         
<!-- END FORM -->
```

The function called from my class ABB:

```
# Save ABB
    public function spara_abb($ident) {  

    // Does IDENT exist?
    $abb_existerar = $this->abb_existerar($ident);

    try{                
        if ($abb_existerar === true){
            $query2  = $this->db->prepare("
                UPDATE `abb` SET `arbetsomrade` = :arbetsomrade,`syfte` = :syfte,
                `overgripande_mal` = :overgripande_mal, `undervisning` = :undervisning,
                `redovisningsform` = :redovisningsform, `lid` = :lid, `datum` = :datum,
                `aktiv` = :aktiv    
                WHERE (`ident`=:ident)");
            $query2->bindParam(':ident', $ident, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':arskurs', $arskurs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':amne_id', $amne_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->bindParam(':arbetsomrade', $arbetsomrade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':syfte', $syfte, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':overgripande_mal', $overgripande_mal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':undervisning', $undervisning, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':redovisningsform', $redovisningsform, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':lid', $lid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->bindParam(':datum', $datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':aktiv', $aktiv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->execute();

        }else {

            $query2  = $this->db->prepare("
            INSERT INTO `abb` 
            (ident, arskurs, amne_id, arbetsomrade, syfte, overgripande_mal, undervisning, redovisningsform,lid,datum,aktiv) VALUES (:ident, :arskurs, :arbetsomrade, :syfte, :overgripande_mal, :undervisning, 
            :redovisningsform, :lid, :datum, :aktiv) ");    

            $query2->bindParam(':ident', $ident, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':arskurs', $arskurs, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':amne_id', $amne_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->bindParam(':arbetsomrade', $arbetsomrade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':syfte', $syfte, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':overgripande_mal', $overgripande_mal, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':undervisning', $undervisning, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':redovisningsform', $redovisningsform, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':lid', $lid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->bindParam(':datum', $datum, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query2->bindParam(':aktiv', $aktiv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query2->execute();

        }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

} // END save ABB
```

Comment: I see you only send $_POST['ident'] to the function, where are all the rest? And where are you creating the object of class ABB?

Comment: @Yair.R I think that´s the problem. I don´t really know how to handle the rest of the information sent from the form. Do I need to add more to the call of the function?

$save_abb = $abb->spara_abb($_POST['ident'], $_POST['arskurs']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the form variables inside of an array and send it to the function like this:

```
$array = Array(':ident' => array($_POST['ident'], PDO::PARAM_INT),
               ':lid' => array($_POST['lid'], PDO::PARAM_INT),
               ':datum' => array($_POST['datum'], PDO::PARAM_STR),
               ':amne_id' => array($_POST['amne_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT));

$save_abb = $abb->spara_abb($array);
```

Now in class you could do something like this:

```
# Save ABB
public function spara_abb($array) {  

// Does IDENT exist?
$abb_existerar = $this->abb_existerar($array);

try{                
    if ($abb_existerar === true){
        $query2  = $this->db->prepare("
            UPDATE `abb` SET `arbetsomrade` = :arbetsomrade,`syfte` = :syfte,
            `overgripande_mal` = :overgripande_mal, `undervisning` = :undervisning,
            `redovisningsform` = :redovisningsform, `lid` = :lid, `datum` = :datum,
            `aktiv` = :aktiv    
            WHERE (`ident`=:ident)");
            foreach($array as $key => $val){
                $query2->bindParam($key,$val[0],$val[1]);
            }
            $query2->execute();
  ....
  ....
```

That way you pass all the variables to the class. I would recommend to make sure that all the variables exist with the function isset(), for example:

```
$idnent = isset($_POST['ident'])? $_POST['ident'] : '';
```

**edit:** Use var_dump($array);

to print all the array and see if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you @Yair.R. Great idea and I gave it a try. Now something is saved to the database. But only the value '1'.

The array seems to fill the database with the last value in the array = 1. 

How do I change the foreach to bind the right values from $_POST in the array?